# improve union of 2 arrays in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, performance

Is there a way to make this way of making a Union of 2 arrays A and B in c++ faster (given any `n`)?
I have beeing thinking but can not see other way...

```
double *A = (double *)malloc( n*n *sizeof(double));
double *B = (double *)malloc(   n *sizeof(double));
double *U = (double *)malloc((n*n+n) *sizeof(double));


int i=0, ci=0;
for (i = 0; i <n*n; i++)
    U[ci++] = A[i];
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    U[ci++] = B[i];
```

Comment: Well, you can always use `memcpy`.

Comment: What you have there is not a union. Perhaps you should rephrase the question?

Comment: Ah, I see you are trying to make a union of two arrays, a new array `U` that contains both `A` and `B`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't an asymptotically better way to do this, because you have to copy over every element exactly once.  However, you might be able to do better by using a bulk copy operation like `memcpy` to do the work for you:

```
double *A = (double *)malloc( n*n *sizeof(double));
double *B = (double *)malloc(   n *sizeof(double));
double *U = (double *)malloc((n*n+n) *sizeof(double));

/* Copy over A onto U. */
memcpy(U, A, n * n * sizeof(double));

/* Append B to U. */
memcpy((char*)U + n * n * sizeof(double), B, n * sizeof(double));
```

This may be faster because the logic to copy the bytes over may be hand-optimized.

You've tagged this question with C++, though it looks more like C code.  That said, if you are using C++, you could write it like this (using `std::copy`):

```
double *A = new double[n * n];
double *B = new double[n];
double *U = new double[n * n + n];

std::copy(A, A + n * n, U);
std::copy(B, B + n,     U + n * n);
```

Or, better yet, using `std::vector` with no exposed memory management or pointers:

```
vector<double> A(n * n);
vector<double> B(n);

vector<double> U;
U.reserve(A.size() + B.size());
U.insert(U.end(), A.begin(), A.end());
U.insert(U.end(), B.begin(), B.end());
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @ruakh- D'oh.  I should proofread better.  Fixed again.  I guess `std::copy` and `memcpy` don't work the same way, which is rather surprising.

Comment: In fact I would like to avoid for loops, do you think this std::copy would work for very large arrays like 1,000,000 elements?

Comment: @cMinor- Yep - `std::copy` works for arbitrarily-sized ranges of elements.

Comment: @cMinor: Internally, `std::copy` is implemented using a loop. All copy operations are, of course.

Comment: But memcopy? does it passes a block of memory? lets say the start of a memory  adress??

Answer (score 2):

Since all you do is concatenating two memory blocks, you can use `memcpy`:

```
double *A = (double *)malloc( n*n *sizeof(double));
double *B = (double *)malloc(   n *sizeof(double));
double *U = (double *)malloc((n*n+n) *sizeof(double));
memcpy(U, A, n*n *sizeof(double));
memcpy(U+n*n *sizeof(double), B, n *sizeof(double));
```

If hardware provides single-instruction copying, you may get some performance improvement from it. On the other hand, optimizers can probably figure out what you're doing anyway, and replace your code with calls to `memcpy` for you.

Answer (score 0):

If this is really supposed to be C++ and not C then you should be using C++ constructions like `std::vector`.

I believe the code would look like (although I have not tested it):

```
size_t n = 100;
std::vector A(n*n);
std::vector B(n);
std::vector U;

U.reserve( A.size() + B.size() );
std::copy(A.begin(), A.end(), std::back_inserter(U));
std::copy(B.begin(), B.end(), std::back_inserter(U));
```

If you actually mean a union as in a union set that has no duplicate numbers, then you need to sort both `A` and `B` then use the `std::set_union` function.